# Play song if sensor detects certain amount of movement

Tags: java, android, loops, nested-loops, android-sensors

I am basically trying to call different songs whenever the sensor detects a change in movement for example...

If no movement is detected play song 1. 
If movement is detected play song 2.
Else if movement stops play song 1 again.

So far, I have been successful and where I am now plays through the first two If statements above, however, I can't get it back to song 1 without the music player playing over itself. I've tried using `.pause();` but it only seems to pause for a second and plays song1 over itself again and again.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
            float x = se.values[0];
            float y = se.values[1];
            float z = se.values[2];
            mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
            mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x + y * y + z * z));
            float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
            mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter

            mp1.start(); //song1 starts

            if (mAccel > 5) { // movement
                mp2.start(); // start song2
                if (mp2.isPlaying()) { // if song 2 is playing stop song1
                    mp1.stop();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 1 media player object, not 2 of them.  By re-using the media player you will ensure that only 1 sound will be played at once whilst also keeping system resource usage low.

Create a new function that will stop the media player and then release it like:

```
private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

Then add a function to re-create and start the media player going with the new audio.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly, don't know why I didn't think of this. I also realized that my line `mp1.start()` should have been inside of my onCreate method which is why it was doubling over itself.